# Filling a Pond to replace with Patio! Advice?

Tags: pond, patio

I have a really ugly pond in my garden that was created by the previous owner. I want to remove the pond and instead extend my patio so I can have a dining area where it is.

The pond is a concrete pond. What would be the best way to do this? My current ideas are:
-Empty it of water, etc. Then fill with concrete so it’s level with the existing patio. Cover old and new patio with decking tiles so it’s all level and matches in.
-Empty it of water etc. Smash up the pond. Fill with loose rubble and then do top soil, then get a patio/deck installed professionally.

I haven’t got a budget as such but I am by no means made of money! I’m leaning towards option 1 as it seems the easiest and most cost effective? With little outside help required. However open to any and all advice. Would really like the patio to match throughout tho, at present it’s a bit of brick, but of concrete and then this pond area.

Comment: where do you live, because old and new concrete can cause problems with ice? Have you considered a small garden in place of the pond, and expanding around it, because the plants that will hit the water will love it?

Comment: I live on the south coast (Dorset) so we don’t usually suffer too bad unless another beast from the east hits. The garden is quite big and we’ve already got all the plants we want but we really want a dining area

Comment: Any future owner will NOT appreciate an 8X8X2 foot, or whatever, chunk of concrete under the soil. Plants will die there. Go with the holed bottom, and maybe even sledge down the sides. If it's a cruddy job, an 8 pound sledge should bust it up easily.

Comment: My opinion (which is frowned upon here, I understand) is that you should simply bust a couple of holes in the bottom (low point, especially), fill it with gravel and deck over it. If the walls are too high, you could knock them down to below grade. Wasting good money and sweat filling it with concrete is a waste of money and sweat.

Comment: Filling it with concrete is not going to be cheap. Concrete is expensive. There's also no need to to that.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate Cruddy topsoil may be even cheaper than gravel, and comes in handy 50Lb bags that you can put in your car. I'd go with 6 or more holes. Going to need a sledge and maybe a chisel for that. You don't want a mini-swamp